# How to keep typescript class and descendants in different files if they refer to each other?

Tags: typescript

I created a typescript class that was intended to have children of the same class.

So for example,

```
 export class Person {
     name : string;
     student1: Person;
     student2: FrenchSpeaker;
     speak() {
         console.log("Hi there.")
     }

     constructor(name : string) {
       this.name = name;
     }
     addStudent() {
        this.student2 = new FrenchSpeaker("Jacques");
     }

 }
```

so Frenchspeaker is a modest extension of Person:

```
export class FrenchSpeaker extends Person {
     speak() {
        console.log("Mai Oui!")
     }
}
```

This all works fine when Person and Frenchspeaker are defined in the same file, but try to separate the two classes in their own files, and it fails to run.  (Although there are no errors showing in VS Code when I do this.  Its' only when I run or test thea pplciation).

FrenchSpeaker obviously has to import Person to extend it.  Person needs to import FrenchSpeaker in order to be able to add a child who is a French speaker.

he real life problem has much more bigger classes, but the error I am getting when seems like it is the result of this sort of circular definition problem.  Yet in this case, where an object contains a collection of objects derived from the same base class as itself, you are forced to stuff all the related classes into a single file, which in my case makes for very long files which are unnecesarily difficult to navigate.

Without complexifying the object graph, by say making Person and FrenchSpeaker inherit from a common ancestor, is there some way to overcome this issue other than putting the two class definitions in the same file?

Comment: What bundler you use for the project? Webpack?

Comment: yes webpack ...

Comment: Commonly, circular dependencies tell you that your code structured in a wrong way. The best way to solve such problem is to refactor your codebase.

Comment: Also, if you can't see no other way than to place all of your structures in one module to solve circular dependency, that's a signal that code structured bad.

Comment: i don't think there's anything wrong with athe structure.   what's the structural problem with an object. having a collection of child objects of a descendent type?  in the general, say a type of document object containing subsidiary document objects or an account containing si accounts.   my feeling is that the conclusion that that circular dependencies indicate bad structure is an evil oversimplification